# Ruby on Rails with IBM_DB2 Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, db2, multiprocessing

Currently, I'm trying to migrate a large data set from an IBM DB2 database. I found a quick way of doing queries using imb_db2 gem (version 4.0.0).

The main goal is to have a script that runs in parallel and imports independent data.

My import script works fine sequential, but when trying to execute the script into multiple background processes, it crashes the process.

I tried Sidekiq with multiple processes, each process with its own queue.

For example, I try the following approach

```
DemoWorker.set(queue: :que_1).perform_async(1, 10)
```

Then I do

```
DemoWorker.set(queue: :que_2).perform_async(11, 20)
```

Each queue has its independent Sidekiq process, with concurrency 1. E.g.

```
bundle exec sidekiq -e development -C config/sidekiq.yml -q que_1
```

And I execute the following code with a query as a parameter

```
  def get_by_sql(sql)
    data = []
    stmt = IBM_DB.exec(self.conn, sql.squish)

    while row = IBM_DB.fetch_assoc(stmt)
      data << row
    end

    data
  end
```

And from time to time I get the following crash error.

**[BUG] object allocation during garbage collection phase**

I have no idea why it fails, could you advise? Thank you very much!

And here is the crash report: https://ufile.io/fqmfh0y8

EDIT:
Crash Report uploaded to GIST: https://gist.github.com/RaresSalcudean/db8467bc4cd3ea2164bcaab5da86780e

Crash 2 Report: https://gist.github.com/RaresSalcudean/6f7bb7f74e34a537b687c776d806bf04

Comment: Can you please upload the stack trace to a gist and share the link? You said it crashes from time to time, does that happen when you have too much data? If so you could try using batches https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of your code, but if you share `self.conn` between different threads you might want to stop doing so.

Comment: @SgtPepper I uploaded the crash report on gist. Actually, I build a query that returns data from DB2 in batches, around 50_000 / or 10_000. And the user Active Record Import, to import the data.

Comment: @mustaccio I am a bit confused because if I use multiple processes of Sidekiq with concurrency 1, aren't they actually different threads? They should do independently create a new connection...

Comment: Doing a bit of research with the backtrace you provided, I found this could be a Redis issue, one guy mentioned ```I noticed the Redis class makes no attempt to automatically disconnect/quit its client connection when the Redis object is garbage collected and instead appears to force the application to manage that. ``` Other guy mentioned ```I have also manually added a bunch of redis.disconnect! calls around our application to mitigate this.``` take a look at this as a reference https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/524

Comment: @SgtPepper Thank you for the feedback! I actually made it work. I downgraded to Rails 5.1 from 5.2 (required for IBM_DB gem) and changed the job processor to Resque. And removed the GEM bootsnap. Using Resque, with 10 processes each with a concurrency of 1, all works as expected.

Comment: Digging into the logs, I found out a trace from bootsnap, that actually seemed suspicious.